# Iterating through a number and rearranging in descending

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rearrange an input number using a function so that a single number is rearranged into descending order.

For example, `234892` would result in `984322`.

This is what I have come up with.

```
function descendingOrder(n){
var num = '';
for(var i = 0; i <= n.length + 1; i++){ // iterates through the number
  for(var j = 9; j >= 0; j--){  // starts at 9 and checks numbers descending
    if (j == n[i]){
      num.push(n[i]);  // checks if j == n[i] and if so, pushes to num
      }
      i = 0; // sets i back to 0 to rescan the number again
    }
  }
return num;
}
```

Comment: So what does the function you posted actually result in?

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: Quite inefficient but fun: `+(234892 + '').split('').reduce((p, c, i) => (p[144 - c * 16 + i] = c, p), []).join('')`. I don't think it deserves an answer, right? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can convert number to string, split each character, sort it and join it again:

```
+(234892 + '').split('').sort((a, b) => a < b).join('');
```

```js
var ordered = +(234892 + '').split('').sort((a, b) => a < b).join('');

document.getElementById('output').appendChild(document.createTextNode(ordered));
```

```html
234892 → <span id="output"></span>
```

Detailed explanation:

```
var str = 234892 + ''; // convert to string
var parts = str.split(''); // convert to array of characters
// sort
parts.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a < b;
});
var finalStr = parts.join(''); // join characters to string
var finalNumber = +finalStr; // convert back to number
console.log(finalNumber); // 984322
```

Comment: nice, and with one line!

Comment: This works! Thank you.

`function descendingOrder(n){
 return +(n + '').split('').sort((a, b) => a < b).join('');
 
}
`

Comment: I have a question that will follow up on this because I have never seen this before, but including the + at the very beginning of the output seems strange to me.

`function descendingOrder(n){
 return +n.toString().split('').sort((a, b) => a < b).join('');
 
}`


Without the +, it does not work?
What is the explanation behind this? 

Thank you for your quick help. :)

Comment: This is what I had originally done but I was getting errors and tried to solve it using a more complex method. lol

Comment: @KevinMurphy `+` converts the output from string to number.